# RPi 4B fails to output to monitor after boot

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display

I'm trying to configure an RPi 4B as part of my homelab alongside other, older RPis. My usual steps would involve:

- Installing an OS (usually either Debian or Ubuntu server) using the Raspberry Pi Imager on a macOS host
- Connecting the Pi to a monitor (typically my 1440p/120Hz Asus monitor) over HDMI
- Configuring network connectivity and provisioning it with my SSH keys
- Attaching the bootstrapped Pi to its permanent physical location in my home, and then configuring it for whatever specific task I expect it to fulfill (so, say, configuring a DNS server, or a print server, or some combination of things)

This is my first experience with a model 4-series Pi, and I can't get it to consistently output to any display available to me, including the Asus monitor I've used in the past and a somewhat older, 1080p TV panel. Originally, I suspected the monitors may have feature sets (like HDR, or high refresh rates, or resolutions over 1080p) that might just disagree with the Pi, but it's not *clearly* that, since (depending on the OS I try this with), I might get either the Ubuntu RPi boot colour gradient and then a boot log, or the Raspbian boot log with the RPi logo tiled along the top of the screen, or just a boot log with Debian (which are the three OSes I've tried so far, both desktop/DE and server versions for Raspbian and Ubuntu).

Additionally: the Pi stabilizes in a state where there's a steady red light with intermittent short flashes of the green light. Keyboard inputs don't seem to have an effect, but the keyboard itself is recognized since I can type in characters in the middle of the boot log (though this isn't a shell, unfortunately; it's the same effect as typing while `tail -f`-ing a live log file).

I'm having some trouble figuring out what causes this behaviour on the 4B, and it seems strange to me that this would be a regression compared to older-model Pis. Is this a known issue with a solution? If not, what are some good diagnostic steps I can take from here given that I functionally have no access to this Pi?

Comment: Incidentally 1440p is ambiguous - what is the default resolution of your monitor? The Pi4 does not support some monitors/resolutions which do not use even clock rates. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#raspberry-pi-4-hdmi-pipeline

Comment: The monitor's native resolution is 1440x2560 @Milliways.